# Using Fancybox but the light box is not appearing - just a redirect to my images

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, gallery, lightbox

I want to use fancybox to show images in my portfolio. However I'm using mapping instead of individual images and I'm not sure I'm coding it right. Whenever I click on an image, it redirects to the image which is completely denying the codes. I've used mapping and lightboxes before, but I needed a new style as I want to completely makeover my website.

This is my result: http://antonybearpark.co.uk/whiteweb/type.html

Before I also had individual projects in separate galleries but keeping to the same pages, but without even getting the lightbox to work, I can't figure this out also.

My previous design is on http://antonybearpark.co.uk/

Please help, I'd be happy to provide people with more information if needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this script:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
 openEffect : 'none',
 closeEffect : 'none'
});
```

however, you don't have any element with `class="fancybox"`. That is creating this error:

```
Error: $(".fancybox").fancybox is not a function
Source File: http://antonybearpark.co.uk/whiteweb/type.html
Line: 99
```

Which is breaking your fancybox code. Try removing the script above and debug your js errors, that might solve your issue.

## UPDATE 1:

For galleries using `area map` tags, you should add the same `data-fancybox-group` attribute to each `area` tag, rather than the `rel` attribute, so instead of this:

```
<area shape="poly" class="fancybox-button" rel="fancybox-button"  ...
```

use this:

```
<area shape="poly" class="fancybox-button" data-fancybox-group="fancybox-button" ...
```

For different galleries,just use a different value for the `data-fancybox-group` attribute. e.g.:

Gallery 01:

```
<area shape="poly" class="fancybox-button" data-fancybox-group="gallery01" ...
<area shape="poly" class="fancybox-button" data-fancybox-group="gallery01" ...
```

Gallery 02 (using another map)

```
<area shape="poly" class="fancybox-button" data-fancybox-group="gallery02" ...
<area shape="poly" class="fancybox-button" data-fancybox-group="gallery02" ...
```

Comment: Tha fancybox js file is not in the place you specified: http://antonybearpark.co.uk/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.0.4 .... check the path for most of your js files, including the mousewheel plugin

Comment: Found it!! is here: http://antonybearpark.co.uk/whiteweb/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js but your path is /fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js so is looking for it from the root but it is actually under the "whiteweb" sub-directory

Comment: ok thanks. it now works. However the arrows don't appear so you can click to the next image which is what I originally wanted. And is it possible to have the two or more separate galleries using different images with arrow buttons to click through on the same page and same image map?

Comment: For the arrows and galleries questions, see my update in the answer above

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript you're targeting the parent alone.
`$(".fancybox-button").fancybox({...});`

I've had better results using a container, like you've done, but also using 'each':

```
$(".hero img").each(function() {
 $(".hero a").fancybox({
 'transitionIn' : 'fade',
 'transitionOut' : 'fade'
...
...
});
```

Where all my images share a common 'rel' tag

```
<div class="hero">
    <a rel="client" href="#"><img src=...></a>
    <a rel="client" href="#"><img src=...></a>
    <a rel="client" href="#"><img src=...></a>
</div>
```

hth